# Is it okay for a 7-month old baby to play with a receiving blanket?

Tags: infant, toys

One of my son's favorite things to do is to push the receiving blankets we've been using to wipe his face right into his mouth, and to hug and snuggle them against his body.

I know that we've been told not to let him sleep with these in his crib - but is it okay for him to play with them when he's awake?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's fine, with normal supervision levels.

Not having the blanket in the crib is to minimise the risk of SIDS - Sudden Infant Death Syndrome, when babies die in their sleep for no apparent reason (pretty scary, yeah). There are safe sleep guidelines:

- put the baby to sleep on its back on a firm mattress
- use a baby sleeping bag, or tuck any sheets or blankets in firmly (some say not have sheets or blankets at all, besides a fitted sheet)
- no loose toys or blankets, or anything else, in the cot
- make sure the baby/room is not too hot

Breastfeeding, and a non-smoking environment, also reduce the risk of SIDS

More info here:
https://safetosleep.nichd.nih.gov/safesleepbasics/risk/reduce
https://rednose.org.au/article/red-nose-six-safe-sleep-recommendations